# Question about big op and little op

Tags: analysis

I'm studying statistical theory and found statement which is

$a_n(U_n - u) = O_p(1)$ implies

$(U_n - u) = O_p(a_n^{-1}) = o_p(1)$

what I don't understand is last equation which is $ U_n - u$ is $o_p(1)$

how this can be possible?? any hint may helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the assumption that $a_n \to \infty$.

---

Choose some $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta > 0$.

We have $P(|U_n - u| > \delta) = P(a_n |U_n - u| > a_n \delta)$.

Because $a_n(U_n - u) = O_P(1)$, there exists $M$ and $N_1$ such that $P(a_n|U_n - u| > M) < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N_1$.

Since $a_n \to \infty$, there exists $N_2$ such that $a_n \delta \ge M$ for all $n \ge N_2$.

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: thanks i'll check that additional condition